# source command not working when used in Perl script

Tags: perl, cgi

Consider the below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
$value="export PI = 3.14";
open(IN,">>/root/.bashrc");
print IN $value;
close(IN);
`source /root/.bashrc`;
```

I want to create an env variable using a Perl script.
I've given 777 permissions to the root folder as well as the .bashrc file.
The $value in the script is getting appended to .bashrc but when i use "env " or "printenv" to display env variables, i cant see the one which is appended to .bashrc.I guess the source command is not working, because when i source the .bashrc file from CL its showing in the env list.Please help me out or suggest another way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've given `rwx` to the root's home directory?  Are you running this as root?

Comment: This approach is not going to work.  Please explain the underlying goal you are trying to achieve so we can suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backticks start a subshell process where the source will be executed. And then will the subshell exit and your perl script will not be effected. Have you tried $ENV{PI}=3.14;? This will alter the environment of the running perl script and all afterwards created subprocesses.

```
use strict ;
use warnings ;

$ENV{TEST} = 'Yo.' ;

my $subshelled = qx!echo \$TEST! ;
chomp $subshelled ;

printf "Subshelled result: '%s'\n" , $subshelled ;

my $subshellenv = qx!env! ;

printf "Env:\n%s\n" , $subshellenv ;
```

will print

```
Subshelled result: 'Yo.'
Env:
...
TEST=Yo.
```

Comment: when i'm trying to execute the above code,it's displaying setting env variable, but it's not storing permanently

Comment: It is storing it permanently for the duration of the perl script - if you want it to exist in the shell that calls the perl script, you need to `source` it in there instead

Comment: I want to source it inside the same perl script

Comment: @PraveenkumarKumbham you cannot influence the environment of a running perl script from outside the script. You can only make changes from within the script.